Configure terragrunt to use a specific version of opentofu
Due to the decadence of terraform (which is nowadays nonfree/proprietary software), I have in most of my main.tf a restriction to use the latest free version, 1.5.7, like:
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.0.5, <1.6.0"
}

Nowadays opentofu, the terraform successor, is out with v1.8.0 and I'd like to try it out.
How do I relax the version requirements so that higher versions can be used, but only from opentofu? For example, how do I pin opentofu v1.6.2 (recommended first step) in terragrunt?
OpenTofu version constraints and Terragrunt IaC engines didn't answer the question.
